# My processor supports 64-bit hardware, but It is for Windows. How to understand If I can run 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit

I checked my processor and It supports 64-bit hardware as you can see down below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGRTF.png)

But Securable talks about Windows. I want to download Ubuntu. Can I still go for it?

Thanks much.

Comment: These Atom Z-Series CPUs support 64 Bit Ubuntu. Be advised though, that the current Linux kernels are not yet perfectly tuned for those processors.

Comment: You have a 64-bit processor.  You are able to use a 64-bit version of Linux.  This does not mean the performance will be any difference compared to a 32-bit Linux kernel

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try now.

Comment: BTW, you might just try it from a Live USB. This allows you to test the new OS without having to install it. Quickly try different distros, this way.

Answer (score -1):

Press and hold the Windows Key and the Pause key.

In the System window, next to System type it lists 32-bit Operating System for a 32-bit version of Windows, and 64-bit Operating System if you're running the 64-bit version.

If you have a 64-bit then you should be able to install Ubuntu x64 version.

Comment: Windows flavor does not matter if the installer is going to put a Linux version on another hard disk or partition without the involvement of the Windows platform. As mentioned above in Ramhounds comment. It is the system being used. Peace. ;-)